# How does % find the index which to split an array in python

Tags: python

So I am working on a codility training and working on the CyclicRotation where you rotate an array a given number of steps. I have found several solutions and the one that looks the best does not really make sense to me.

So the solution is:

```
def solution(A, K):
    if not A:
        return A
    if K == 0:
        return A
    K = -K % len(A)
    print(K)
    print(A)
    print(A[K:])
    print(A[:K])
    return A[K:] + A[:K]
```

So I get the splitting of the array by K as this will give you how many should move. But i don't get how to get K. Why do you take the -K and then % by len of the Array? That part does not make sense to me.

Comment: Do you understand how the modulus operator works?

Comment: Yes it returns the remainder after the division of two numbers. But I dont understand the logic behind why to do that.

Comment: `solution([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2) = [3, 4, 0, 1, 2]`. `3 == -2 % 5`. It's counting `K` positions from the right. But modulus also cycles, so you can also have `k == 7`

Comment: _Yes it returns the remainder after the division of two numbers. But I dont understand the logic behind why to do that._ Then that's a mathematics or computer science question, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine repeating your array infinitely in both directions. So, for example, if you have

`A = [0,1,2]`

imagine

`[...,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,...]`

Say we want to circular shift `A` to the right by `1`. Our array `A` should go from `[0,1,2]` to `[2,0,1]`. The last element should become the `0`'th, and every other element should advance by 1 position. In terms of `solution`, we want `solution(A,1)`.

One way to think of this is that instead of starting our array at index `0` (the middle `0` value) in our infinitely-repeated array and taking the next `3` values, we can start at index `-1` and take the next `3` values. Then, instead of having `[0,1,2]`, we'd have `[2,0,1]`. That's what we want.

Likewise, if we want to circular shift `A` to the left by `1` (which would be `solution(A,-1)`), we can start at index `1` and count `3` values from there instead. Note that if we want to shift right, we move our index left, and vice versa.

This process is exactly what `K = -K % len(A)` does. The `K = -K` part of it deals with the fact that if you're shifting right, you can do that by moving your index to the left along the infinite sequence. The `% len(A)` part of it essentially treats `A` as an infinite sequence.